# Why is the output of these 2 programs different on codeforces while they are the same on ideone?

Tags: c++, output

First program:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,taken,i,j,ans=0,t,num,k;
cin>>n>>t;
vector<int>a(n);

for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];

i=0;j=0;    
for(;i<n;++i)
{
    if(i>j)
    {
        j=i;
        k=0;
        taken=0;
    }

    for(;j<n;++j)
    {
        if(taken+a[j]<=t)
        {
            taken+=a[j];
            k++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    ans=max(ans,k);
    taken-=a[i];
    k--;
}

cout<<ans;
return 0;
}
```

Second program:

```
  #include <bits/stdc++.h>
  using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,taken,i,j,ans=0,t,num,k;
cin>>n>>t;
vector<int>a(n);

for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];


for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    if(i>j)
    {
        j=i;
        k=0;
        taken=0;
    }

    for(j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        if(taken+a[j]<=t)
        {
            taken+=a[j];
            k++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    ans=max(ans,k);
    taken-=a[i];
    k--;
}

cout<<ans;
return 0;
```

}

it seems these 2 programs give 2 diffrent outputs,here is a testcase to check it out yourself:
4 5
3 1 2 1

the first one outputs "3" while the second outputs "1991243264
" on codeforces tests while the 2 programs give the same output on ideone..any help?

Comment: Why do you `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`? Who's teaching this?? :(

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>`, `using namespace std;`, and a bunch of early declarations. Ouch.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This [Google result](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/8387) made me cringe. And I don't think it being from CodeForces too is a coïncidence.

Comment: I have seen this trend in competitive programming that people include `bits/stdc++.h` so that they don't have to care whether they have included the proper header file or not.I am not a supporter of it.

Comment: it's a habit to save time during a contest..i usually write this now even if i don't need to include many headers to solve a specific problem,as for the `using namespace std` part...when i first learned c++ i learned it this way so it's kind of a habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first program you are setting the values of `i` and `j` outside the for loops and then only changing `j` inside the if statement in the outer for loop.

```
//...
if(i>j) 
{
    j=i; //<- set j here
    k=0;
    taken=0;
}

for(;j<n;++j) //<- using j from above
{
//...
```

In your second piece of code you are resetting `j` to zero each time the for loop is ran.  You also never set `j` to a value before you enter the first for loop so when you use `j` in your if statement it will invoke [**undefined behavior.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

```
//...
if(i>j) // j is uninitialized here so you could get anything
{
    j=i; //<- set j here
    k=0;
    taken=0;
}

for(j=0;j<n;++j) //<- set j to zero here
{
//...
```

Comment: Just a technical/nitpick question.  Isn't using an uninitialized int is unspecified behavior (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) instead of undefined behavior?

Comment: @user3282085 I am pretty sure this falls under the UB banner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The second program invokes undefined behavior, since you read the value of `j` in the first iteration of the outer for-loop without first initializing it. The general result of this type of UB is reading whatever random data happened to be in that stack location... and that depends on a lot of factors, and is likely to differ between environments.

There's also a bunch of other stuff wrong in those programs. But purely in terms of why it's giving you different results.... that's why.

Answer (score 0):

In the second program `j` is uninitialized.

```
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
{
   if(i>j)//j is uninitialized here
    {
```